# Gogole MLKit model takes longer than expected to process

Tags: java, android, image-segmentation, google-mlkit, segmentationselfie

I want to use Google MLKit Android SDK for segmentation, and following its [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation/android) I made this simple code using latest API version (`com.google.mlkit:segmentation-selfie:16.0.0-beta4`). I'm running on a Samsung S10+ which has a good GPU and the official MLKit camera segmentation app runs smoothly with 25-30 fps. But when I calculate the time it takes for the model processing like below, it shows almost 100ms only for the model to return the result. Let alone the mask processing, etc. This is much longer that what is needed for real-time processing. Am I missing anything? In particular,

1. Is my approach to calculate the segmentation processing time correct?
2. Are there any tips or tricks or ways to optimize the processing further, maybe trading for a lower quality segmentation?

[image]

```
    SelfieSegmenterOptions options =
            new SelfieSegmenterOptions.Builder()
                    .setDetectorMode(SelfieSegmenterOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                    .build();
    Segmenter segmenter;
    segmenter = Segmentation.getClient(options);


    InputImage image;
        image = InputImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap, Surface.ROTATION_0);

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    Task<SegmentationMask> result =
            segmenter.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener<SegmentationMask>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(SegmentationMask segmentationMask) {
                                    // Task completed successfully

                                    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                                    String time = "Time: "+(endTime - startTime)/1000000f +" ms";
                                    timeTextView.setText(time);

                                    ByteBuffer mask = segmentationMask.getBuffer();
                                    int maskWidth = segmentationMask.getWidth();
                                    int maskHeight = segmentationMask.getHeight();

                                    // the rest of code...mask processing and making it pink
                                }
                            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    // Task failed with an exception
                                }
                            });
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include what device/OS version you are testing on, in addition clarify the size and orientation of the input image. Be aware that you've selected `SelfieSegmenterOptions.STREAM_MODE` but you seem to inputing a static image which should use `SINGLE_IMAGE_MODE`

Comment: No change when I switch it with single image. But in my code eventually it needs to process frames one after another.